Do evil people also have hope? (Tikvat reshaim)
There is a concept in Shaar Gilgulim, that there are certain great but evil men, who have a great potential, but they are doing mostly evil due to the origin of their soul. However, since every soul/human has a holy part, they therefore usually do something very very good during their lifetime.
Some examples could be:

Bilaam, the evil magican (who blessed Israel)
The rebellious Korah (whose descendants were very righteous)

Etc. It was explained that (the soul part of?) Bilaam finally appeared later in a good incarnation (because he was overwhelmed by his good inclination at a critical moment).
The question is: does this explanation diminish the possibility of teshuva? Since if somebody has such a great soul but his soul is mostly from the evil side, that compels him to do great but cruel, immoral, etc. things. On the other hand, if somebody has a holy soul root he will do certainly good things, because that is his inclination by birth.
Did the explainations about the motivations of souls in Shaar HaGilgulim  change the traditional rabbinic view about the scope of free will and the possibility to self refinement, after the spread of the teachings of Arizal?
I think these texts should change how we are viewing individual human life stories and human history as whole, and they raise a lot of questions.

This answer seems to be presuming that the Arizal innovated, rather than taught us genuine, eternal Torah. There are two ways to answer this that I can think of. One along those lines: yes he innovated, and therefore might have contradicted some earlier sources, but had perhaps some on his side, just like most Rabbinic innovations do. Or the other answer, by those who believe he had ruach hakodesh, and was revealing and filling in the mystical tradition, will hold that he isn't innovating, and one will find that his ideas don't contradict, and are hinted at in earlier sources, largely.
